# Change props of component after it's pushed into an array?

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of components with the following props:

```
<TourCard
props={props}
key={address.id}
address={address}
history={props.history}
virtualId={virtualId}
removeIndex={props.removeIndex}
tourCards={props.tourCards}
setTourCards={props.setTourCards}/>
```

My concern is with this prop:

```
tourCards={props.tourCards}
```

tourCards is the array that I'm pushing the  component into.

My problem is that the value of tourCards is out of date on a component once I've added another component to the array.

```
[<TourCard/>, <TourCard/>, <TourCard/>]
```

How can I change/update the value of the prop tourCards in the TourCard component at index 0 in the array to reflect the updated state as at exists in the last component in the array?

```
<button onClick={() => {
                      props.setTourCards(cards => {
                        const virtualId = cards.length
                        console.log(virtualId)
                        let polylinePathCopy = props.polylinePath
                        polylinePathCopy.push(pathCoordinates)
                        props.setPolylinePath(polylinePathCopy)
                        return [...cards, 
                        <TourCard
                        props={props}
                        key={address.id}
                        address={address}
                        history={props.history}
                        virtualId={virtualId}
                        removeIndex={props.removeIndex}
                        tourCards={props.tourCards}
                        setTourCards={props.setTourCards}/>]
                      })
                    }}
                    >
                      Add to tour
                    </button>
```

And here where tourCards is rendered

```
return (
          <>
          <section className="planSection">
            <div>
              <PlanMap
              loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
              containerElement={<div style={{ height: `400px`, width: `400px` }} />}
              mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
              />
            </div>
            <section className="tourSection">
              <button onClick={() => {
                props.setTourCards("")
              }}>Clear tour</button>
              {props.tourCards} 
            </section>
          </section>
            </>
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to update a prop of array type (so you can trigger a `componentUpdate`), you can do something like this:

```
tourCards = [...tourCards];
```

Comment: how would I use that method in context?

Comment: Since in `<TourCard>` the prop `tourCards` is determined by `props.tourCards` which I suppose is passed down to it by the parent component of `<TourCard>`, you probably want to update the `props.tourCards` in the parent component.

Comment: I've added more of my code to the original question. Where/how in between the button onClick and the return statement would I update the tourCards prop of the <TourCard> component?

Comment: The reason I asked this question is because I have a delete function that's supposed to delete components from the array, but the state of tourCards in the first component is that there's only one item in it, so if i delete the first component in the array, it deletes anything after it.
const removeIndex = (index) => {
    let holdingArray = tourCards
    holdingArray.splice(index, 1)
    setTourCards(holdingArray)
  }

Comment: your `holdingArray` is not a "holding array" it's still referencing `tourCards`